# Finding the difference in value and date between rows in a pandas dataframe given a conditional column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, difference, datediff

I'm trying to find a way to compute the difference in values of a particular column, as well as, the difference in dates based on the values of a third column that has the values of 0 and 1.

My initial data frame looks like this:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[-15, -10, 40, -25, -50,-90, 200], 
                   'date': ['2018-01-20', '2018-01-19','2018-01-19',
                            '2018-01-18', '2018-01-17','2018-01-16', 
                            '2018-01-15'],
                   'flag':[0,0,1,0,0,0,1]})
```

The flag column takes a value of 1 whenever the value column is greater than zero and 0 otherwise. Assume it is sorted by date. Given this dataframe, I want to compute the change in value and date with for each row where the flag is equal to 0 with respect to the closest, earlier date, flag equal to 1.

The resulting df should look like this:

[image]

Here, the first time we had a positive value is 40. The difference between 40 and -10 is 30, and the cumulative difference between this value and -15 is 15.

Answer (score 1):

That is not different(`diff`) , this is `sum` for value

```
df=df.sort_values(['date','flag'],ascending=[True,False])#sort your df 
df['diff_value']=df.groupby(df.flag.cumsum()).value.cumsum()#get the cumsum with flag key 
df['diff_days']=df.groupby(df.flag.cumsum()).date.apply(lambda x : x.diff().dt.days.fillna(0).cumsum())#get the days different . 
df=df.sort_index()
df
Out[436]: 
        date  flag  value  diff_value  diff_days
0 2018-01-20     0    -15          15        1.0
1 2018-01-19     0    -10          30        0.0
2 2018-01-19     1     40          40        0.0
3 2018-01-18     0    -25          35        3.0
4 2018-01-17     0    -50          60        2.0
5 2018-01-16     0    -90         110        1.0
6 2018-01-15     1    200         200        0.0
```